# How can I use standard input for openvpn configuration?

Tags: openvpn

Here is what I want to accomplish:

`gpg -d -a < myconfig.ovpn.enc | openvpn`

This doesn't work, of course, because openvpn doesn't look at stdin for config information.  Does anybody know how to make it do that?

Comment: You can pass the configuration filename as `--config <filename>`.  Now, in this case, you might be able to  cheat and use `/dev/fd/0` or `/dev/stdin` as the filename :-)

Comment: That's a great hack, and it's working.  Very clever!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Stephen Harris' comment above, this works great:

`gpg -d -a < xAptive.ovpn.enc | sudo openvpn --config /dev/stdin`

Comment: Works without the first redirect and --config option: `gpg -d -a xAptive.ovpn.enc | sudo openvpn /dev/stdin`